# How do I configure PHP server to look in public folder?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've just been following along this tutorial on using Zend Framework 1 with composer - http://adamcod.es/2013/05/10/composer-and-zend-framework-1.x.html

I got as far as downloading and installing ZF1 as a dependency then rewriting index.php to look inside vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/ directory for the Zend library (instead of library/). I can confirm this is OK by going to localhost /zend-composer/public/

However, when I start up PHP server `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` it tells me `The requested resource / was not found on this server.` as it is looking in the root directory.

I'm kinda new to PHP server, perhaps I need to configure something? Would appreciate any advice on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use -t option for a public directory

> php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t web/

For zend should the following work

> php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/

Answer (score 1):

This practice is commen in ZF2 - It is important to define both document_root and router

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t public public/index.php
```

Where  `-t public` defines the document_root to be public directory

And `public/index.php` defines the router script, and all request will be passed to script (normally defined by `mod_rewrite` in apache.